# Proving Gauss’s summation theorem for the $q$-binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs, q-series

I am following Warren P. Johnson's "An Introduction to q-analysis". We are supposed to prove $$\binom{n+1}{k+1}_q=\sum_{m=k}^{n}q^{m-k}\binom{m}{k}_q$$ Here is my attempt.

We start off by using the $q$-analogue of Pascal's identity, which is $$\binom{n+1}{k}_q=\binom{n}{k}_q + q^{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k-1}_q$$

Setting $n=n-1$ grants
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k}_q = \binom{n-1}{k}_q + q^{n-k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}_q
\end{align}

Substitute this back into the equation we started with, repeat this for (say) $m$ times to get

\begin{align}
\binom{n+1}{k}_q = \binom{n-m}{k}_q + \sum_{i=0}^{m}q^{n-k-i+1}\binom{n-i}{k-1}_q
\end{align}

How do I complete the proof? I understand that I have to choose the "right" value for $m$ and then set $k=k+1$.

Comment: Try setting $k=k+1$ instead and you are done.

Comment: @Somos, don't I need to pick an appropriate $m$ before setting $k=k+1$?

Comment: You can keep applying Pascal's identity until the first binomial coefficient is $\binom{k}{k}_q$ (after which it will be zero). So when you say "repeat this $m$ times", the correct value for $m$ would be $n-k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result to prove is

$$ \binom{n+1}{k+1}_q=\sum_{m=k}^{n}q^{m-k}\binom{m}{k}_q. \tag1 $$

The $q$-analog of Pascal's identity is

$$ \binom{n+1}{k}_q=\binom{n}{k}_q + q^{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k-1}_q. \tag2 $$

Replace $k$ with $k+1$ to get the identity

$$ \binom{n+1}{k+1}_q=\binom{n}{k+1}_q + q^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}_q. \tag3 $$

Move the $\binom{n}{k+1}_q$ to the other side to get

$$ \binom{n+1}{k+1}_q - \binom{n}{k+1}_q = q^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}_q. \tag4 $$

This implies that equation $(1)$ is a telescoping sum.

Notice that when $n=k-1$ then $\binom{n+1}{k+1}_q = 0.$

The result follows.